# Need assistance in designing Django model for a school management system app

Tags: django, database

I am trying to create a school management app, and I want to have place where a school admin can create a weekly schedule for a class. I have the below structure in mind for this.

```
{
    "grade": 1,
    "shortBreak": "10:00am - 10:15am",
    "longBreak": "1:00pm - 2:00 pm",
    "monday": [
                {
                    "time":"09:00am - 09:30am",
                    "subject":"English"
                },
                {
                    "time":"09:30am - 10:00am",
                    "subject":"Math"
                },{
                    "time":"10:15am - 10:45am",
                    "subject":"Science"
                },
            ],
    "tuesday":[
                {
                    "time":"09:00am - 09:30am",
                    "subject":"Maths"
                },
                {
                    "time":"09:30am - 10:00am",
                    "subject":"Social Sciene"
                },{
                    "time":"10:15am - 10:45am",
                    "subject":"Sports"
                },
            ],
    "Wednesday":[
                {
                    "time":"09:00am - 09:30am",
                    "subject":"Maths"
                },
                {
                    "time":"09:30am - 10:00am",
                    "subject":"Social Sciene"
                },{
                    "time":"10:15am - 10:45am",
                    "subject":"Sports"
                },
            ],
    "Thursday":[
                {
                    "time":"09:00am - 09:30am",
                    "subject":"Maths"
                },
                {
                    "time":"09:30am - 10:00am",
                    "subject":"Social Sciene"
                },{
                    "time":"10:15am - 10:45am",
                    "subject":"Sports"
                },
            ],
    "Friday":[
                {
                    "time":"09:00am - 09:30am",
                    "subject":"Maths"
                },
                {
                    "time":"09:30am - 10:00am",
                    "subject":"Social Sciene"
                },{
                    "time":"10:15am - 10:45am",
                    "subject":"Sports"
                },
            ],
    "Saturday":[
                {
                    "time":"09:00am - 09:30am",
                    "subject":"Maths"
                },
                {
                    "time":"09:30am - 10:00am",
                    "subject":"Social Science"
                },{
                    "time":"10:15am - 10:45am",
                    "subject":"Sports"
                },
            ],
}
```

The challenge I am facing is that I don't know how to add array fields in Django models and how to have multiple objects in an array and store it in db. Please help me understand how I can achieve the above structure in Django.

Answer (score 0):

You can create selection fields for known fields(days of week and subject) and create a separate model for schedule.

Comment: thanks for that Ricardo!! Can you tell me how I can create an array of objects.

Comment: you can use append function.For example, list_name.append(class_name(fields))